# How to remove the Title-bar of a LWUIT Form?

Tags: java-me, lwuit, lwuit-form, lwuit-button

In the `actionPerformed` of a `Button` I want to remove the `Title-bar` of the actual LWUIT `Form`. How to achieve that? And how to redisplay it again after a certain action has been complete?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use below code for hide/show the title of the `Form` in the `Button` action event,

```
final Form form = new Form("Sample");
form.setLayout(new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
final Container titleContainer = form.getTitleArea();
titleContainer.setVisible(false);
Button b = new Button("button");
b.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
    if (!titleContainer.isVisible()) {
       titleContainer.setVisible(true);
    } else {
       titleContainer.setVisible(false);
    }
    form.revalidate();
    }            
  });
form.addComponent(b);
form.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also just do

```
form.getTitleArea().setVisible(false);
```